# Fixtures installation error in sylius?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sylius

*I want to install fixtures in sylius*  *i used below command to install it that are as below*

> php app/console sylius:install --fixtures

*when i ran above command i get error as*

## >PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale.php on line 51

```
PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\app\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\app\console:28
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfon
y\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:106
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src
\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:78
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\s
rc\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:193
PHP   6. Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Command\InstallCommand->execute() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfony
\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:242
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\CoreBu
ndle\Command\InstallCommand.php:80
PHP   8. Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand->execute() C:\wamp\www\syliu
s\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:242
PHP   9. Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->execute() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\doctr
ine\doctrine-fixtures-bundle\Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php:106
PHP  10. Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->transactional() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\doctrine\data-fixtures
\lib\Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor.php:85
PHP  11. call_user_func() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php:2
23
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\{closure}(
) C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php:223
PHP  13. Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor->load() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendor\doc
trine\data-fixtures\lib\Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor.php:83
PHP  14. Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCountriesData->load() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\vendo
r\doctrine\data-fixtures\lib\Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor.php:120
PHP  15. Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale::getDisplayCountries() C:\wamp\www\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\
CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCountriesData.php:31
```

*I try to install resource bundle when i got the above error but it also failed to install.*

**Is there any other way is avilable to install fixtures in sylius?**

*Please share some knowledge..Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `intl` installed on your environment. Symfony does not provide a stub class for "en" locale.

Comment: I have symfony project in Windows 2008 server. I have installed and activated `intl`. But in `phpinfo()` I am not able to see `intl`. and I get same error